# How I can get the first post category using get_the_category() with Timber?

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

I have the postID, and I need use get_the_category(). Doing :

```
{{ function('get_the_category', event_id) }}
```

this return just the string "Array", but I need the first category. I need something like:

```
{{ function('get_the_category[0]', event_id) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Timber has a [`get_terms`](https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/TimberPost#terms) method for getting the terms attached to a post, you can combine it with the Twig [`first`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/first.html) filter to get only the first term:

`{{ post.get_terms('category')|first }}`

Comment: Wohooo, never heard about the `first` filter before. This is great!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used this way:

```
{{ function('get_the_category_list', '', '', event_id) }}
```

This give me the complete list of categories, but I had to hide the rest with CSS. Dirty.